# Show message to rotate the phone in portrait mode (for website)

Tags: joomla, landscape

My site looks bad in portrait mode, but it's ok in landscape.
I want to show a message to users that suggest user to rotate the phone to view page correctly.
My site is in Joomla.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

There are several extensions available for Joomla to allow you to display nice looking popup messages. But it would be easier to use Javascript to detect whether a users device is in portrait and to then show a message.

```
if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    alert("Please use landscape!");
}
```

The above code will only show the message "Please use landscape!" if the users device is in portrait mode. Run that JS code at the top of your page and it should work nicely.

**Edit:** For this to work when the viewport is only 600px high:

```
if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    if(window.innerHeight < "600"){
        alert("Please use landscape!");
    }
}
```

Comment: this works.  I think this should be marked as answered.  it does exactly what @Elfiszcze asked for.  - now to find a way to only make this happen when the viewport is less then - say - 600px in height ---

Comment: @sheriffderek adding another if statement to the above should accomplish this, edited the answer.